# What is the email SPF entry for sending from Yahoo!?

Tags: email, spf, spam

I have a client that is sending email from a Yahoo! Plus account as if from her own domain. Is there a way to set up the SPF record so that it covers all of Yahoo!'s outgoing servers? i.e., what do I put for **YAHOO_SPF** here in the TXT record?

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +YAHOO_SPF ?all
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer (use this in your TXT record):

```
 "v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.mail.yahoo.com ?all"
```

So far the answers all show the `host` command. Which is fine.

"dig" / "host" / "nslookup" all work for Linux and grabbing TXT records.

`dig` is my favorite:

```
 dig @ns1.yahoo.com yahoo.com TXT
```

Will show you all the TXT records (and SPF) for the domain (apex in this case).

Under **Windows** CMD or Powershell use `nslookup`:

```
 nslookup -type=TXT yahoo.com
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>nslookup -type=TXT yahoo.com
Server:  my.localdomain
Address:  10.10.10.1

Non-authoritative answer:
yahoo.com       text =

        "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mail.yahoo.com"
yahoo.com       text =

        "facebook-domain-verification=gysqrcd69g0ej34f4jfn0huivkym1p"
yahoo.com       text =

        "edb3bff2c0d64622a9b2250438277a59"
```

or for an authoritative answer:

```
 nslookup -type=TXT yahoo.com ns1.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 8):

Yahoo now provides an SPF record:

```
$ host -t txt yahoo.com
yahoo.com descriptive text "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mail.yahoo.com"
```

[Details on their policy here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN24016.html).

Answer (score 2):

While [Google Apps makes this simple](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786), I don't think Yahoo! does.

[Yahoo! favors DomainKeys](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/context/context-07.html) over SPF, to the point that they don't publish SPF records for their own domain:

```
$ host -t txt yahoo.com
yahoo.com has no TXT record
```

The other think to think about is that this rule could presumably allow anyone else with a Yahoo! Plus account to spoof mail from your domain (assuming proper controls were not implemented on the Yahoo! side when the mails were accepted).

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo.co.uk still don't have spf information:

```
host -t txt yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.co.uk descriptive text "Yahoo! Inc."
```